# PySpark: String Split / Expand Columns

Tags: pyspark

While there are many threads on the topic, the examples are not working for me.

Consider the following:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['1', 'SN4.F01C04-AM428.1_31']]), ["col1", "col2"])

+----+--------------------+
|col1|                col2|
+----+--------------------+
|   1|SN4.F01C04-AM428....|
+----+--------------------+
```

What I tried:

```
display(df.select(F.split(df.col2, '.', 1).alias('s')))
+--------------------+
|                   s|
+--------------------+
|[SN4.F01C04-AM428...|
+--------------------+
```

Expected:

```
expected = spark.createDataFrame(sc.parallelize([['1', 'SN4', 'F01C04-AM428', '1_31']]), ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])

+----+----+------------+----+
|col1|col2|        col3|col4|
+----+----+------------+----+
|   1| SN4|F01C04-AM428|1_31|
+----+----+------------+----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` is a special character that needs to be escaped when used in the split function. The requirement is to convert the `array` column into multiple columns, which can be implemented as follows:

```
df = df.select('col1', *[F.split('col2', '\\.').getItem(i).alias(f'col{i + 2}') for i in range(3)])
```